# Why my redis added a key to a second node

Tags: redis

I am new with redis. I added one key, but when I checked all the nodes it seems that this key is on two of them

If I understand correctly, I have the same key on `127.0.80.122:6379` and `127.0.212.159:6379` node:

```
redis-cli --cluster call 127.0.245.125:6379 KEYS my_key
>>> Calling KEYS group*
127.0.80.122:6379: my_key
127.0.125.17:6379:
127.0.212.159:6379: my_key
```

I can successfully get a value of this key from `127.0.212.159:6379` node, but when I am trying to get it from: `127.0.80.122:6379` I am getting `(error) MOVED 9644 127.0.212.159:6379` error. What does it mean? Is it in two, or one node?